# activity does not close after taking picture Android

Tags: android

Hi i have used SurfaceView and taking picture by below code

First i am starting activity by this code

```
     startActivityForResult(new Intent(PictureEditor.this, CustomCamera.class), CAMERA_REQUEST3);
```

and then getting result from this code

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST3) {
            BitmapFactory.Options abc = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            abc.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "tester.png"), abc);
            abc.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(abc, w, h) + 1;
            abc.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            view.setBackBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "tester.png"), abc));

        }
```

Now the CustomeCamera Class's code is below

```
          // / Handles when mTakePicture is clicked
private OnClickListener mTakePictureAction = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mCamera != null)
            mCamera.takePicture(CustomCamera.this);


    }
};
```

Then

```
        @Override
    public void takePicture(Activity activity) {
        if (mCamera != null)
            mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        activity.setResult(mActivity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        activity.finish();
    }
```

the problem is image is captured but the activity is not getting finish! Can anybody suggest me what to do!

Comment: i think activity should be finish .You should be fire another intent in which activity which u want to go

Comment: What's the difference between ``activity`` and ``mActivity`` ?

Comment: Ya there is previous activity which call this activity it should be start !

Comment: Why do you say that your activity is not getting finish ? (i.e. what's the behaviour of your app and what did you expect ?)

Comment: Can you show us more of your code? What is `mActivity` here? Can changing `mActivity.finish()` to `activity.finish()` help?

Comment: Can you please show your code ?

Comment: wait i am editing question again with code

Comment: Also it might be worth noting that ``Camera.takePicture`` is asynchronous. Maybe it was best to finish your Activity only after saving the final picture.

Comment: there are total 4 methods you can use differently to finish one activity.. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29 Read the document .. and implement it. 
also check what your 'activity' object contains.. because if finish() is called on an Activity then it will surely get closed.. if not getting closed problem is with your 'activity' object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to write code for finish activity in onActivityResult() in previous activity from where this activity starts.

So your previous activity finish . . .

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode)
    {
         case YOUR_REQUEST_CODE:
                               finish();
    }
}
```

**Edit :**

First change this code.

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
activity.finish();
```

then in onActivityResult() first check the request code condition then after in request code condition check result code condition.

Comment: but Chirag this finish will finishing current activity!

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit Please post this code in your previous activity.

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit Do you want to finish previous or current activity ?

Comment: Ya i want to finish CustomCamera Activity by this way i am capturing photo and send it back to my previous activity it is same like open android camera but here i have to do overlay that's why i have to make my custom camera code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21448/discussion-between-siddhpura-amit-and-chirag-raval)

Answer (score 0):

I have a strong feeling that main (UI) thread is stuck while

```
   @Override
public void takePicture(Activity activity) {
    if (mCamera != null)
        mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    activity.setResult(mActivity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    activity.finish();
}
```

I am not too sure where it is being stuck (from code example above), 
possibilities

1) picture cannot be saved

2) picture cannot be encoded

and etc

You can test it by running debugger